# Where to find an 0805 SMD LED in Altium?

Tags: altium

I'm trying to learn to use Altium and am having a really difficult time finding components. I discovered capacitors and resistors in `Vault Explorer->Unified Components->Components - Generic`, but how do I find other basic elements such as LEDs?

I tried searching the vault for `LED`, but there are thousands of search results and I can't figure out a way to specify a package type (I'm wanting 0805).

EDIT:

I assume it's a good idea to try to avoid making new components in Altium (i.e. re-inventing the wheel) because it takes a long time.

To my knowledge, making a new component in Altium requires these steps (at a minimum):

1. Creating a new schematic and PCB library or adding existing ones to the project
2. Finding the IPC footprint standards document
3. Create the footprint (add the pads, draw the outlines, etc.)
4. Create the 3D model
5. Attach 3D model to footprint
6. Create the schematic symbol
7. Add footprint to schematic symbol
8. Add 3D model to schematic symbol
9. Edit pins to match between schematic symbol and PCB footprint
10. Fill in all of the other information for the component

For me, at least, all of this takes a *really* long time!

Comment: Just create an LED part with an 0805 footprint!

Comment: if you are learning to use altium, avoid the vault. use the integrated libraries and learn to make your own footprints and symbols.

Comment: @LeonHeller You make a custom part for every component you place? It seems like there would be a better (faster) way of doing things.

Comment: If you'd made your own part, you'd be done by now!

Comment: I use Pulsonix and that has many of the parts I use in the libraries. Making custom parts doesn't take long, if I need to do it.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Doubtful, see my edit.

Comment: You will already have the footprint and other stuff. You just have to associate the LED symbol to it.

Comment: I NEVER use library parts. Every part in my library was made by me. The reason? I don't have to worry if whatever jackwagon made it paid attention and got the footprint right. It takes 2 minutes.

Comment: @LeonHeller Unlike Olin's comment, yours is actually helpful. So now my question is, how do I `already have the footprint and other stuff`? Where does that stuff come from?

Comment: @Matt: Yup, that's what I do too. I use Eagle, but the principle is the same. It would take me longer to vet a part made by someone else than to make it the right way in the first place. Nate: Especially if you're trying to learn, make the part yourself. This is a important skill. You need to feel you can make a new part easily whenever the situation arises.

Comment: @MattYoung How do you make a part in 2 minutes? Are there any resources you can point me to? I'm brand new to Altium and the  few parts I've made from scratch so far took quite a while to make. Leon mentioned already having the footprint and other "stuff" -- is there a way to not have to make everything totally from scratch?

Comment: I don't use Altium, but the same principle can be applied to any EDA tool. Accumulate a set of common footprints as you go, SOIC, TSSOP, MSOP, .1" headers, whatever SMT passive size you use, etc. That is the time consuming part. After that, adding a new resistor, for example, takes 30 seconds. A 100 pin part will take longer, as you have to type the names in from the datasheet. This is all faster that verifying someone else's work. Best advice I can give you is keep a 1:1 pin mapping, and the rest will come with time and practice.

Comment: I think it is so bloody annoying that each software has its own format and most/none of the part manufacturers publish the models for their products. 10000 clicks to design something into Eagle, move it to Altium, then again to Solidworks, and so on. This is all so stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making the footprint is generally one of the fastest of all the things you need to do. There are Wizards in Altium that help you make IPC-compliant footprints quickly, and you can set the text height, silk screen line widths and so on to conform to your specific requirements and so your boards have a consistent appearance and set of manufacturing requirements.

Populating the data base with all the things that *should* be there (vendors, part numbers, alternates, prices, and so on) takes longer. Making a 3D body, if you need to, can take a lot longer depending on your proficiency with 3D parametric modelling software and whether you want to do a good job, a spectacularly good job, or something more slapdash. Here's a rendering of an LED body I did some time ago- the actual die dimensions and position is shown but I didn't bother with the bond wire. The typical library parts often have a crude 3D block or nothing at all.

[image]

You only make the part *once* and you can re-use it thereafter. It's a big hassle to add parts to inventory for the rest of the company, so maybe it will make you think twice about reuse.

Anyway, if you're at the beginner stage (we've all been there) and you just want to get going, use an 0805 resistor and it will be sub-optimal but usable (ignoring the 3D features and such like). You can edit it to show the polarity and save it in a library of your own. You can also download someone else's library that's been done more-or-less properly and (hopefully) learn from that and create your own as you gain experience. IIRC, the 0805 and other Imperial standard footprints may use the metric equivalent numbers (2012 for 0805) as part of their names.

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer! I wasn't aware of the footprint wizard in Altium and that will save a TON of time. As you mentioned, it also generates the silkscreen, etc., which is also a time saver.